# Сортировка по числовому доп полю AFC wordpress

Tags: wordpress, acf

Столкнулся с проблемой, сделал числовое поле через ACF
хочу сортировать и вывести, но ничего не выдает

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge(
    $wp_query->query_vars, ['posts_per_page'=>999, 'meta_key'=>'statia', 'orderby'=>'meta_value_num','order'=>'ASC']
);

query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
```

либо пытался через functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);
function my_pre_get_posts($query)
{

    if ($query->query['category_name'] == 'posts') { // вместо 'events' указываем ID нужной категории
        $query->set('key', 'statia'); // сортировка по произвольному полю
        $query->set('orderby', 'value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); // порядок сортировки
    } 
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}
```

Выводится 7 постов из 50

Comment: В остальных постах наверное поле пустое?

Comment: @WPPunk сначала были пустые, потом везде добавил, но нигде не появились

Comment: $query->set('key', 'statia'); => $query->set('meta_key', 'statia');
$query->set('orderby', 'value_num'); => $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
Попробуй поменять на эти значения и сделать через new WP_Query